# Design html page using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to design the following html page using bootstrap:

[image]

this is what I get till now [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1NqThFLL4OKiNU1OeW8?p=preview)

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Please be specific about your issue by describing it, what is wrong with what you have? what you have tried...? Your question, as it is written  doesn't show much effort to achieve your goal and will shurely be closed shortly.

Comment: @web-tiki : I have added link for plunker in my question that should be enough to show my efforts. My problem is that I am getting every thing in same column. While I need it to be in a grid like layout having two rows and two columns and each of them having one list and that  is shown in posted image (in question it self).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using *Bootstrap 3* with *Bootstrap 2* semantics.

For *Bootstrap 3* there is no `.row-fluid` or `.span` CSS classes.

You should do it like this:

- add a `.container` or `.container-fluid` if you want a fluid layout
- add `.row` to define a grid row
- add `.col-md-6` to tell a div to take half of the 12 grids

You should read the documentation here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Also, an example of what I said above can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mS5Vb/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>General</h3>
      <div>
        <div>General 1</div>
        <div>General 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Semantic</h3>
      <div>
        <div>Semantic 1</div>
        <div>Semantic 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Type</h3>
      <div>
        <div>Type 1</div>
        <div>Type 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Forest</h3>
      <div>
        <div>Forest 1</div>
        <div>Forest 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```